# Django: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'

Tags: django

Django's new model class could not be successfully migrated, reported an error, how do I need to change this error

```
Django 2.1.7
Python 3.6.5
```

In the previous version of ORM, you can also migrate normally, but after changing some code, it will not migrate properly.

> File
>   "C:\Users\senyu\Anaconda3\envs\py3.6.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\com
>   mands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
>       fake_initial=fake_initial,   File "C:\Users\senyu\Anaconda3\envs\py3.6.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\execu
>   tor.py", line 117, in migrate
>       state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fak e_initial)   File
>   "C:\Users\senyu\Anaconda3\envs\py3.6.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\execu
>   tor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
>       state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "C:\Users\senyu\Anaconda3\envs\py3.6.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\execu
>   tor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
>       state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Users\senyu\Anaconda3\envs\py3.6.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migra
>   tion.py", line 114, in apply
>       operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, project_state)   File "C:\Users\senyu\Anaconda3\envs\py3.6.5\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\opera
>   tions\fields.py", line 144, in state_forwards
>       delay = not old_field.is_relation AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'

Comment: How do you expect us to help you if you don't show any of your code or what you're doing to produce the error? Please write your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

You've run into a Django bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28073. You probably have a `migrations.RemoveField` in one of your migrations. Somehow your database table and the migrations got out of sync.

It seem that the solutions is to inspect and manually edit your migration. I can't provide an exact solution because it depends on your models.